# How do I get a value of an item from dictionary while executing dictionary expression?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, expression

I would like to ask how do I properly transform this code into dictionary expression?

```
con=[['mon','2'],['jun','3'],['mon','3']]
data={}
for x in con:
    if x[0] in data:
        data[x[0]]=int(data[x[0]])+int(x[1])
    else:
        data[x[0]]=int(x[1])

print data
```

The output will be:

```
{'jun':3,'mon':5}
```

I tried this but it doesn't add the value of 'mon':

```
data={}
data={x[0]:(int(data[x[0]])+int(x[1]) if x[0] in data else int(x[1])) for x in con}
```

The output is :

```
{'jun':3,'mon':3}
```

maybe because the dictionary data is empty . Is it possible to get a value from dictionary data while executing it?

Please let me know if my question has a duplicate. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that your problem is that you can't access the `dict` as you're building it. Here is a workaround. For each key `k` in `con` it finds all the locations `k` in `con`, and sums the corresponding values. For each `k` it does a list comprehension.

CODE:

```
con=[['mon','2'],['jun','3'],['mon','3']]
data = {k: sum(int(con[i][1]) for i,(x,_) in enumerate(con) if x == k) for k,_ in con}

print data
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'jun': 3, 'mon': 5}
```

Comment: @hobo you actually don't need zip, it looks a lot better now and should be a lot faster

Comment: Thank you very much. :-)